# How to access bios on ubuntu (to change settings)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, dell, bios

I may sound dumb for asking this but i am trying to install windows 8 on virtual box it says in order to run it i have to access bios and activate/turn on something.

it wants me to Enable VT-x and Enable VT-d

PC: dell Optiplex 745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VT-X And VT-D Are in your virtual machines settings in the boot order. But to activate any of the both. You need to turn on virtualization in your BIOS. For your PC, It should be F2. Then Go and change the following:

```
Security > Execute Disable (set to On)
Performance > Virtualization (set to On)
Performance > VT for Direct I/O Access (set to On)
Performance > Trusted Execution (set to Off)
```

Activating virtualization in the BIOS should let you boot your virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a VirtualBox you have a virtual BIOS. You will find it in the machine's configuration in VirtualBox.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't allow you to do that on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

For sony vaio users you need to press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter into bios. You will find VT-x in 'Advanced' tab not security. Enable it and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to save and exit.